# How to create Toast Notification with custom icon and custom app name?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, toast

I'm trying to create a Windows Toast Notification with .Net C#. While this, I would like to change the notification icon and the app name in the attribution area (header) of the notification.

I'm able to place a notification with a custom "App name" like shown here:

[image: My screenshot of the following code]

I do this with this code:

```
var toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);

var stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
stringElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Title"));
stringElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Message"));

ToastNotification toast = new(toastXml);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("App name").Show(toast);
```

But I don't find a solution, how to place an icon left from "App name".

The solution can't be to modify the toast on a different way, since it only changes the visual or action elements. But not the attribute area:

[image: Screenshot from Microsoft]

How can I show an icon in the attribute area?

Answer (score 1):

To set the icon in the attribution area you can set it directly.

```
var toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);

var stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
stringElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Title"));
stringElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Message"));

ToastNotification toast = new(toastXml);
// here you set your icon
toast.attribution.icon = new ToastImageSource("path to your image");
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("App name").Show(toast);
```

To set the icon in the title you can change the created toast.

```
var toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);

var stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
stringElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Title"));
stringElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Message"));

ToastNotification toast = new(toastXml);
// Here you can change the visual element of the toast
// don't know which image will be correct. Can't test at the moment
toast.Visual.TileLarge.HintRemoveMargin = true;
toast.Visual.TileSmall.HintRemoveMargin = true;
toast.Visual.TileMedium.HintRemoveMargin = true;
toast.Visual.TileLarge.Branding = ToastBranding.Logo;
toast.Visual.TileSmall.Branding = ToastBranding.Logo;
toast.Visual.TileMedium.Branding = ToastBranding.Logo;
toast.Visual.TileLarge.AppLogoOverride = new ToastAppLogo();
toast.Visual.TileSmall.AppLogoOverride = new ToastAppLogo();
toast.Visual.TileMedium.AppLogoOverride = new ToastAppLogo();
toast.Visual.TileLarge.AppLogoOverride.Crop = new ToastAppLogoCrop(0, 0, 1, 1);
toast.Visual.TileSmall.AppLogoOverride.Crop = new ToastAppLogoCrop(0, 0, 1, 1);
toast.Visual.TileMedium.AppLogoOverride.Crop = new ToastAppLogoCrop(0, 0, 1, 1);
toast.Visual.TileLarge.AppLogoOverride.Source = new ToastImageSource("file:///C:/path/to/your/icon");
toast.Visual.TileSmall.AppLogoOverride.Source = new ToastImageSource("file:///C:/path/to/your/icon");
toast.Visual.TileMedium.AppLogoOverride.Source = new ToastImageSource("file:///C:/path/to/your/icon");

ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("App name").Show(toast);
```

Additionally you can set an `appLogoOverlay` which is displayed in the title area

```
// get hte ToastGeneric toast content
XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastGeneric);

// here you get the visual element of the toast
XmlNodeList toastVisualElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("visual");

// to add an icon you need app logo overlay 
XmlElement appLogoOverlay = toastXml.CreateElement("appLogoOverlay");
// here you set the source of the overlay 
appLogoOverlay.SetAttribute("src", "path to your icon");
// here you can add style attributes 
appLogoOverlay.SetAttribute("hint-crop", "circle");
toastVisualElements[0].AppendChild(appLogoOverlay);

var stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
stringElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Title"));
stringElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Message"));

ToastNotification toast = new(toastXml);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("App name").Show(toast);
```

Comment: ToastGeneric is not defind on my end. But AFAIK, the `appLogoOverlay` will be displayed left from the text (in my screenshot "Title") and not like I asked in the attribute area left from "App name" in my screenshot. So, I believe, this is not an answer to my question.

Comment: sorry, i cant test this at the moment. i changed my answer. hope this helps.

Comment: You only suggest modifying the toast. But the toast will not modify the attribute area. I've updated my question, to make this more clear.

Comment: have you tried: `toast.attribution.icon` I changed my answer

Comment: Yes, for me, it doesn't work. I suggest, you delete your answer.

Comment: There is no such thing as `toast.attribution.icon` or `toast.Visual`